# xdotool simulate ctrl key holding

Tags: bash, keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse

i need to simulate ctrl key holding for multi selecting action by ctrl and mouse click, so i tried this short key :

```
bash -c "notify-send 'ctrl pressed' 'message';xdotool keydown Control_L ; sleep 4 ;xdotool keyup Control_L ;notify-send 'ctrl released' 'message';"
```

but don't working
[image]

it is working for example 2 key like this:

```
bash -c "notify-send 'ctrl pressed' 'message';xdotool keydown 2 ; sleep 4 ;xdotool keyup 2 ;notify-send 'ctrl released' 'message';"
```

but when i tried that for simulating holding ctrl for 4 second i can not have multi selecting by mouse during this 4 seconds!.

**Update:**

I combined the ctrl+mouse click by this script as short key:

```
bash -c "notify-send 'ctrl pressed' 'message';xdotool keydown ctrl click 1 keyup ctrl --delay 500 keydown ctrl click 1 keyup ctrl;notify-send 'ctrl released' 'message';"
```

but can not do it as multiple click after 1 second delay and mouse new location point for second click! in that script i need to press shortkey (ctrl+1) for second selection and it don't selecting after 500ms in new mouse location!

Thanks.